# Using long int as a parameter for malloc

Tags: c

```
int main() {
int n;
long u=0,d=0,count=0,i=0;
char *p=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
scanf("%ld",&n);
scanf("%s",p);
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
if(p[i]=='U'){
        u=u+1;
    }
    if(p[i]=='D'){
        d=d+1;
    }
   if((d-u)==0 && p[i]=='U'){
       count=count+1;}
}
    printf("%ld",count);
return 0;
}
```

In this standard syntax for implicit memory allocation, if i replace "int n;" with "long int n;"
An error pops up saying:

GDB trace:
Reading symbols from solution...done.
[New LWP 10056]
Core was generated by `solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

I have searched everywhere for a solution, rather i quite dont know what to search for,
i would be greatful if anyone helps me out. Thanks :)
(This was executed on an online compiler)

Comment: What is the value of `n`?

Comment: its 1000000 so i had to declare it as long int rather than int.

Comment: @milan: how does it get that value? Your code shows nothing....

Comment: I have just posted a code snippet, In the actual program, it is initialized by the user as 1000000

Comment: That code does not show that.  `malloc` is called before any user interaction.

Comment: 1. Please don't put code in comments; it is unreadable. 2. Please show the *precise* code that lead to the reported error (you still don't show any initialization of `n`.)

Comment: I have updated the post which contains the full code

Comment: I know that n is uninitialized before calling the malloc function, but how does it  work properly with int.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: The solution is to 1) initialize your variables *before* you use them and 2) check malloc's return value for errors.

Comment: @melpomene (for 1.) yes, i am well aware that i have to initialize my variables before using them, but how can it work fine for just "int" and not for "long int", i searched for the differences between int and long int, and it only said about the storage capacity of each.

Comment: Again, undefined behavior means anything can happen. That includes appearing to "work".

Comment: @milan: since `n` is uninitialised, it will contain some arbitrary value which happened to be in the memory location assigned to it. If `n` is an `int`, that value cannot be larger than `MAX_UINT`, but if `n` is a `long` it could be. `malloc` will return NULL if it cannot allocate as much memory as you ask for. Draw your own conclusion. (I use MAX_UINT and not MAX_INT because the argument to malloc is unsigned and will therefore be converted.)

Comment: BTW, `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed by the language to equal 1 so using that construct just adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @rici if n contains arbitrary value, no matter what the value, it should show an error for both int and long int, or it should execute without error for both,

Comment: @MilanML That is an incorrect assumption. *Undefined behavior means anything can happen.*

Comment: @milan: if the value happens to be 42, the malloc will succeed. If it happens to be 42 thousand million, it will fail. But an int cannot be 42 thousand million. Whereas a random long is almost certainly bigger.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracting the relevant parts of your code:

```
int n;
char *p=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
```

The parameter to `malloc` is of type `size_t`, which is an unsigned type. If you pass an argument of any other integer type, it will be implicitly converted to `size_t`.

You report that with `int n;` you don't see a problem, but with `long int n;` your program dies with a segmentation fault.

In either case, you're passing an uninitialized value to `malloc()`. Just referring to the value of an uninitialized object has undefined behavior.

It may be that the arbitrary `long int` value you're passing to `malloc()` happens to cause it to fail and return a null pointer, causing a segmentation fault later when you try to dereference the pointer; the arbitrary `int` value might just happen to cause `malloc` to succeed. Checking whether `malloc` succeeded or failed would likely avoid the segmentation fault.

Passing an uninitialized value to `malloc()` is a completely useless thing to do. The fact that it behaves differently depending on whether that uninitialized value is an `int` or a `long int` is not particularly significant.

If you're curious, you might add a line to print the value of `n` before calling `malloc()`, and you *definitely* should check whether `malloc()` reported failure by returning a null pointer. Beyond that, you know the code is incorrect. Don't waste too much time figuring out the details of *how* it fails (or, worse, why it sometimes doesn't fail). Just fix the code by initializing `n` to the number of bytes you actually want to allocate. (And define `n` as an object of type `size_t`.)

Some more points:

The code in your question is missing several required `#include` directives. If they're missing in your actual code, you should add them. If they're present in your actual code, you should have included them in your question. Don't make assumptions about what you can safely leave out.

`int main()` should be `int main(void)`. (This is a minor point that probably doesn't make any practical difference.)

```
scanf("%s",p);
```

This is inherently dangerous. It reads a blank-delimited string that can be arbitrarily long. If the user enters more characters than the buffer `p` points to can hold, you have undefined behavior.

```
u=u+1;
```

Not incorrect, but more idiomatically written as `u ++;`.

`(d-u)==0` is more clearly and safely written as `d == u`. (For extreme values of `d` and `u` the subtraction can overflow; an equality comparison doesn't have that problem.)

Comment: Your advices are very valuable, 
I checked the values of n, and it seems that n has a 9 digit value for long int, and a 5 digit value for int, which seems to have caused the problem, 
Thanks a lot, i will keep every point in mind.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that I would like to point out:

1. First of all, you do not have to declare n as "long int". "long int" and "long" are the same. So,

   ```
   long int n; //is same as
   long n;
   ```
2. malloc() works perfectly fine whether n is an "int" or a "long". However, you don't seem to have initialized n. What is the value of n? C does not perform auto-initialization of variables and n might have a garbage value (even negative) which might cause your program to crash. So please give a value to n.

   ```
   long n = 10; //example
   ```

or use a scanf() to input a value.
Now in your code, what is scanf() doing "after" malloc? I presume that you intended to read a value for n and then pass it to malloc. So please change the order of code to this:

```
    scanf("%ld",&n);
    char *p=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
```

I ran your program with these changes on my system and it works fine (no segmentation fault)

3. malloc() limits: We know that malloc allocates from a heap. But I really don't see malloc returning NULL on current platforms (which are generally 64 bit). However, if you do try to allocate a very large chunk of memory, malloc might return NULL which will cause your program to crash.

So it's good to check the return value for malloc() and if that's NULL then take appropriate actions (such as retry or exit the program)

Having a check like the one below will always help:

```
    if (p == NULL) {
       printf("Malloc error");
       exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: thanks. Yes, i agree that changing order corrects the program, but why and how does it execute when i use only "int", it seems to show no error when i use only "int"

Comment: Is the behavior with using n as an uninitialized "int" consistent? I doubt that. Try running several times. Check the return value of malloc() if its NULL then take appropriate action. BTW where are you running the code? If you run that on something like "codechef" (which treats the code like C++) you may have an auto-initialization of n. Try running using gcc. It should crash.

Comment: Try running your "original code" here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php It crashed with seg fault even for int n. So the behavior that you're observing is purely transitory. It's not possible for malloc to behave differently for an int or long int. That's just not possible.

Comment: @MilanML People have tried to answer that question, in the question comments. Undefined behavior means anything can happen; the fact that it appeared to work with `int` means nothing more than the fact that it happened to not work with `long`. Ultimately, nobody can tell what is happening on your system except, perhaps, you (using a debugger to find the instruction that precedes SIGSEGV and working backwards).

Comment: @paratrooper Yes, it is consistent, i compiled it here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/counting-valleys

Comment: @MilanML I ran it on tutorials point and got a seg fault for your code. Just because hackerrank gave you a specific output doesn't mean that malloc is behaving differently. It's possible that they do some internal initialization that we are unaware of. There are hundreds of platforms out there and each can give you a different O/P. That doesn't change the behavior of malloc in any way. I wish to repeat: malloc is defined by standards to work exactly same whether its passed an int, long int or any other variant of int. I cannot emphasize this enough.